# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to access data from commerceJS API fetched on a different module and passed down as a prop, the code only breaks when I call a nested product object with this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')`.

I have used the same API on the storefront and `{product.media.source}` works fine. I'm trying to make a preview module and when I call the nested object it breaks.
Please help.

Here's my code

```
const Preview = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

const params = useParams();



const findProduct = (id) => {
    return products.find((product) => {
        setProduct(product);
        return product.id === id;
    });
};
const productId = params.id;

useEffect(() => {
    findProduct(productId);
});
return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} style={{ marginTop: '90px' }}>
        <CardMedia image={product.media.source} title={product.name}></CardMedia>
        <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='div'>
                {product.name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
                variant='body2'
                color='textSecondary'
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}
            ></Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
            <IconButton component={Link} variant='outlined' to='/'>
                Go Back
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label='Add to Cart' onClick={() => onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>
                <AddShoppingCart />
            </IconButton>
        </CardActions>
    </Card>
);
```

Here's the product Object
[product obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7LCS.png)

Comment: Apparently your `product` object does not contain a `media` field. Can you provide the content of the `product` object?

Comment: Done, you should find a png image up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your `product` object does not contain `media` field by default. You need to wait until it is available before using it.

Try something like this:

```jsx
const Preview = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState();

    const params = useParams();

    console.log(products[0]);
    console.log(params.id);

    const findProduct = useCallback((id) => {
        return products.find((product) => {
            if (product.id === id) { // <-- render optimization
                setProduct(product);
                return true;    
            }
            return false;
        });
    }, [products]);

    const productId = useMemo(() => params.id, [params.id]);

    useEffect(() => {
        findProduct(productId);
    }, [productId, findProduct]);

    const renderCard = useCallback(() => {
        if (!product) return null; // <-- here you can implement your placeholder component
        return (
            <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} style={{ marginTop: '90px' }}>
                <CardMedia image={product.media.source} title={product.name}/>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='div'>
                        {product.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                        variant='body2'
                        color='textSecondary'
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}
                    ></Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                    <IconButton component={Link} variant='outlined' to='/'>
                        Go Back
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton aria-label='Add to Cart' onClick={() => onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>
                        <AddShoppingCart />
                    </IconButton>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        );
    }, [product]);

    return renderCard();
};
```

Or like this:

```jsx
const initialState = { // <-- you need to change this as you need
    active: true,
    assets: [/* ... */],
    categories: [/* ... */],
    checkout_url: {
        checkout: 'placeholder://checkout.url',
        display: 'placeholder://display.url',
        /* ... */
    },
    collects: {/*...*/}
    created: 0,
    description: 'placeholder description',
    extra_fields: [/* ... */],
    hsa: {/* ... */},
    id: 'placeholder_id',
    invenotry: {/* ... */},
    is: {/* ... */},
    media: {
        type: 'image',
        source: 'placeholder://image.source',
        /* ... */
    },
    meta: null,
    /* ... */
};

const Preview = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(initialState);

    const params = useParams();

    console.log(products[0]);
    console.log(params.id);

    const findProduct = useCallback((id) => {
        return products.find((product) => {
            if (product.id === id) { // <-- render optimization
                setProduct(product);
                return true;    
            }
            return false;
        });
    }, [products]);

    const productId = useMemo(() => params.id, [params.id]);

    useEffect(() => {
        findProduct(productId);
    }, [productId, findProduct]);

    return (
        <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }} style={{ marginTop: '90px' }}>
            <CardMedia image={product.media.source} title={product.name}/>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant='h5' component='div'>
                    {product.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    variant='body2'
                    color='textSecondary'
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description }}
                ></Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
                <IconButton component={Link} variant='outlined' to='/'>
                    Go Back
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton aria-label='Add to Cart' onClick={() => onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>
                    <AddShoppingCart />
                </IconButton>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    );
};
```

Comment: It works it works! Thank you!! :D,  It takes some time to load can you say why?

Comment: @CaramelIfy the time it takes to load depends on the internal logic of the hooks used, as well as the logic of the parent components. Most likely you are making an api request somewhere, it takes time

Comment: @CaramelIfy even if the loading time were extremely short, most likely you would still get the same error, because in your code you initially tried to access the field of an `undefined` object

Comment: Well, I guess that makes sense @wowandy thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code above

```
console.log(products[0]);
console.log(params.id);

const findProduct = (id) => {
    return products.find((product) => {
        setProduct(product);
        return product.id === id;
    });
};
```

Looks like the product is an array and not an object. I think this is where you might have missed.

Hence, `product.media.source` throws error as product.media is undefined.

Please check which product you might want to add.